# Computing integral when the derivative factors (separates)

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, plane-curves, implicit-function

I have a specific smooth function $F(x,y,z) = 0$ which implicitly defines a function $\widehat{z}(x,y)$.

In my analysis of this function's properties, the term $$M(x,y) \equiv -\frac{\widehat{z}_y}{\widehat{z}_x}$$ (that is, the ratio of partial derivatives of $\widehat z$) appears frequently. This quantity is evidently the slope of the level curve of $F$ obtained by intersecting with the plane $z = \widehat{z}(x,y)$  ([Geometric meaning of partial derivatives $z_y/z_x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282397/geometric-meaning-of-partial-derivatives-z-y-z-x)).

In particular, I've found a curious property: the mixed partials of $\log{M}$ for my function are identically zero, which means that $M(x,y) = \alpha(x)\beta(y)$ for some functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

My question is:

> *Question*: What does this factorization mean geometrically for the function $F$ and its level curves?

I would think we can define the level curve in terms of an integral over  $M(x,y)$, the slope, but when I write it out, I don't see any simplification to be made when the integrand factors as a product. Is there something we can learn about the level curves in any case?

---

Edit: I note also that

$$M(x,y) \equiv -\frac{z_y}{z_x} = \alpha(x) \beta(y) \quad \Rightarrow\quad \frac{z_y(x,y)}{\alpha(x)} = \frac{-\beta(y)}{z_x(x,y)}$$
but I don't know if this separation leads anywhere.